# System logs in to Administrator

Tags: windows-7, administrator

My Windows 7 system automatically logs into the Administrator account without user input. Why does it do this?

Answer (score 0):

This means you do not have a password set on your administrator account in Windows 7.  If you create a password for this account, it will stop auto logging you in.

To configure a password in Windows 7, do the following:

1. Go to Start > Control Panel
2. In Control Panel, go to User Accounts > User Accounts
3. Click on Manage User Accounts
4. Select the Reset Password in the Password for Administrator frame.
5. Reset your password.

OR you can do it the easy way

1. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL
2. Select *Change a Password* from the list
3. Change your password

Comment: Actually it means they have configured a default account.  You can set the default account even to an account with a password.

Comment: Yes, but the OP specifically states that it was his admin account that was doing this.

Comment: So; any account can be the default account